# Python Tkinter Refresh text in Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter. I need to show in a text box some informations about the ongoing process. The code below prints the two messages at exit. How can I refresh the box whenever I need?

```
Self.txtbox.insert("end", "wait...")
```

do_something_long()
Self.txtbox.insert("end", "done\n")

Comment: you should post an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ... What is the type of `txtbox`

Comment: Apologizes for the bad presentation of the code. I am on my IPad. I did my best but I could not manage to get it right. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *refresh*? Delete all text in it?

Comment: The text box is of type Text.

Comment: Refresh means update. In the sample code, I want to print the "wait..." message BEFORE the tricky calculation starts. By default, the text box is updated at the exit of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Insert this line right after changing the content of the text box will force it to refresh immediately.

```
Self.update_idletasks()
```